# How do I kill Apache HttpClient I/O Dispatcher threads after main() exits?

Tags: java, multithreading, spring, apache-httpclient-4.x, resttemplate

I'm using Spring's [AsyncRestTemplate](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/client/AsyncRestTemplate.html) backed by Apache [HttpAsyncClient](https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-asyncclient-4.1.x/httpasyncclient/apidocs/org/apache/http/impl/nio/client/CloseableHttpAsyncClient.html). My configuration is based on this [blog entry](http://vincentdevillers.blogspot.com/2013/10/a-best-spring-asyncresttemplate.html).

When running my asynchronous code in JUnit, everything exits cleanly. I suspect this is because JUnit kills all running threads when the test method exits.

```
@Test
public void loadFirstSISOfferingFromFactory() throws Exception {
    CourseOfferingService factoryCourseService = ValenceServiceFactory.getCourseOfferingService();
    BlockingQueue<CourseOffering> queue = factoryCourseService.getAllCourseOfferings();
    CourseOffering course = queue.take();
    LOG.info( course.toString() );
}
```

When I run this same test in a main() method (as it will be when deployed), the I/O dispatcher threads fail to exit.

```
public static void main( final String args[] ) throws Exception {
    CourseOfferingService courseService = ValenceServiceFactory.getCourseOfferingService();

    BlockingQueue<CourseOffering> queue = courseService.getAllCourseOfferings();
    CourseOffering course = queue.take();
    System.out.println( course.toString() );
}
```

The code works correctly – that is, it connects to the REST API I expect, loads the correct data, executes the callback method, and populates the queue. The ValenceServiceFactory generates Spring beans (I'm using this so non-Spring enabled projects to access my services). However, when all the connections are idle and the main thread has completed, the I/O dispatcher threads live on.

[image: IO dispatcher threads in the debugger]

Here's my Spring Configuration:

```
@Bean
public RestTemplate restTemplate() {
    RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate( new HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory() );
    restTemplate.setErrorHandler( new DefaultResponseErrorHandler() {
        @Override
        public void handleError( ClientHttpResponse response ) throws IOException {
            // Do nothing when error is found.
            // Hopefully the status code will be passed to the ResponseEntity
        }
    } );

    return restTemplate;
}

@Bean
public AsyncRestTemplate asyncRestTemplate() throws IOReactorException {

    // Configure Apache Http Client
    PoolingNHttpClientConnectionManager connectionManager = new PoolingNHttpClientConnectionManager( //
            new DefaultConnectingIOReactor( IOReactorConfig.DEFAULT ) );
    connectionManager.setMaxTotal( 1000 ); //Total Connections
    connectionManager.setDefaultMaxPerRoute( 900 ); //Max connections per host

    RequestConfig config = RequestConfig.custom() //
            .setConnectTimeout( 60 * 1000 ) // milliseconds
            .build();

    CloseableHttpAsyncClient httpclient = HttpAsyncClientBuilder.create() //
            .setConnectionManager( connectionManager ) //
            .setDefaultRequestConfig( config ) //
            .build();

    AsyncRestTemplate restTemplate = new AsyncRestTemplate( //
            new HttpComponentsAsyncClientHttpRequestFactory( httpclient ), restTemplate() );

    return restTemplate;
}
```

I suppose dropping a `System.exit(0)` at the end of the main method, but if there's a running background process I *want* to complete, it'll be killed immediately, rather than waiting to complete.

Essentially, I'm looking for an equivalent of `java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService.shutdown()` and `.awaitTermination()`, except for AsyncRestTemplate or HttpAsyncClient. In theory, a clean shutdown would be possible after each dispatcher thread has been idle a certain time.

Is that possible? Am I forced to use `System.exit()`?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think you need to shutdown the connectionManager https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-asyncclient-dev/httpasyncclient/apidocs/org/apache/http/impl/nio/conn/PoolingNHttpClientConnectionManager.html#shutdown()

Comment: Yeah, shutting down the connectionManager kills all in-flight connections. I tried `closeExpiredConnections()` and `closeIdleConnections()` to no avail. `shutdown()` kills all connections, but surprisingly, the dispatcher threads live on.

Comment: Destroying the `HttpComponentsAsyncClientHttpRequestFactory` via `destroy()` has the exact same effect: Kills all in-flight connections, and in my test, kills them even before `take()` is finished waiting.

Comment: CloseableHttpAsyncClient#close shuts down the underlying connection pool along with all i/o dispatch threads

Comment: Yeah, the problem is the asynchronous code keeps running, so that results in dozens of Connection Unexpectedly Lost exceptions. Ultimately I had to write custom code to track open (unpoisoned) queues, wait until all queues had been poisoned, and _then_ call close/destroy.

Comment: still has not been resolved for some reason. blek.